# Youtube IFrame api getVideoLoadedFraction() not called in iOS

Tags: javascript, iframe, youtube

I read links about YouTube IFrame API and doing a sample which has iFrame in HTML.

I need the below function to be called:

```
 player.getVideoLoadedFraction();
```

I am using the below code for creating player object.

```
var player;
function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady()
{
     alert('onYouTubeIframeAPIReady');
     player = new YT.Player('player', {
                                   height: '432',
                                   width: '768',
                                   videoId: 'tNpd9LCaG8',
                                   events: {
                                   'onReady': onPlayerReady,
                                   'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
                                   }
                                   });
      alert('player created');
}
```

and for testing purpose I added the `player.getVideoLoadedFraction()` in the `onStateChange` event.

```
function onPlayerStateChange(event)
{
      alert("onStateChange has fired!\nNew state:" + event.data);
      var progress = player.getVideoLoadedFraction();
      alert (progress);
 }
```

this method is not getting called. Even if I put any alert after `var progress = player.getVideoLoadedFraction();` this line, alert is not displaying.

Can anyone help me to solve this.

Thank you

Comment: If you take a look at https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Getting_Started you can see that they are referencing these functions inside `onYouTubeIframeAPIReady` when creating the `YT.Player` object. And so the YouTube player knows about them. Just creating these functions won't attach them to the 'YouTube API'. Edit: Your second function should be called after and if you include the API on your page, as stated in the documentation.

Comment: Thank you. added the API code. now onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() is called. but player.getVideoLoadedFraction(); is not getting called. Where I am missing?

Answer (score 1):

Don't call player.getVideoLoadedFraction(), call event.target.getVideoLoadedFraction().